# ASP.NET Core NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Very tricky situation is happening. I have a create action which works fine if I simply run it `https://localhost:7171/Category/Add`, it all was working fine until I added a new action method that lists the products from the database:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{catname}/{name}")]
public IActionResult Listproduct(string name, string catname)
{
    List<Product> products;
    
    Subcategory subcat = db.Subcategories
                           .Where(x => x.Slug == name && x.Catname == catname)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
    int subid = subcat.SubcatId;

    products = db.Products.ToArray()
                 .Where(x => x.SubcatId == subid).ToList();

    return View(products);
}
```

Create Controller Action method for GET and POST

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(CategoryVM model)
{
    if(! ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    if (db.Categories.Any(x => x.Catname == model.Catname))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", $"{model.Catname} already exists");
        return View(model);
    }


    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string uniqueFileName = UploadedFile(model);

        var dto = new Category
        {

            Catname = model.Catname,
            Slug = model.Catname.ToLower(),
            Description = model.Description,
            CatImage = uniqueFileName

        };
        db.Categories.Add(dto);

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    

    TempData["SM"] = $"{model.Catname} category added to list";
    
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
```

Here is the error screenshot

[image: Error when access any Create action]

Now I am not able to access any of the create actions and it keeps on throwing an error.

I am able to access `Listproduct` action without any issues.And the create actions work when I delete the `ListProduct` action.

Comment: Why does this even compile, did you turn off nullable types? Don't you get warnings from your compiler/IDE? What do you think happens, if no subcategory is found?

Comment: No warning, I have SubcatId added as foreign key in Products Model class with null enabled on it

Comment: Could you please check if `name and catname in your url` is typed correctly and in a `correct order` ? In my test, the code is right but the wrong order makes the query result to be null and brings me the same error .

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using FirstOrDefault() from the where clause

This will either return the first matching record or the default which is null

I would swap to using Find which will automatically return the first element or null and then add null handling if the sub cat doesnt exist

Comment: no success with var subcat = db.Subcategories.Where(x => x.Slug == name && x.Catname == catname).Single();

Answer (score 0):

Okay, lets first fix your method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{catname}/{name}")]
public IActionResult Listproduct([FromRoute]string name, [FromRoute]string catname)
{
    var subcat = db.Subcategories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Slug == name && x.Catname == catname);
    var subid = subcat?.SubcatId;

    var products = db.Products.Where(x => x.SubcatId == subid).ToList();

    return View(products);
}
```

Now even with the fixed method, the question is, why is it even *called*? I don't know, you did not show that part of the code. But it is a "get" without any other route part, in theory with both your parameters being optional, it could be called just by calling the main URL in a browser. So why is it called? You need to find that out, I have no idea what you do. Because even after the fix, it won't crash, but there is still no point in calling it.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Above code lets simply call public IActionResult Listproduct. So now on calling public IActionResult Create or Add again load public IActionResult Listproduct without any results.

Comment: Well, I cannot fix code I cannot see. Please post more code, for example what does this Create method look like?

Comment: Updated my question with Create Action method which redirects to Listproduct Action

Comment: Got it resolved, had to simply update [Route("~/Category/Create")] attribute on each Create Action. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Resolved it by simply adding `[Route("~/Category/Create")]` attribute on each `Get` action like CREATE/ADD.